# Passing current file name to Visual Studio debug command line arguments

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I'm creating PowerShell module in VS 2012. So for comfortable debugging in debug project properties I set Start action to start external program PowerShell.exe and in command line arguments I want to add
-Command { Import-Module [MyDllFileName] }. What should I write instead of [MyDllFileName]? There should be my compiled dll.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass the assembly name as a command-line argument when debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876408/how-to-pass-the-assembly-name-as-a-command-line-argument-when-debugging)

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find it on my own. But that question is 4 years old and that solution won't work for me, because I want to DEBUG my dll, not just only run tests. I want to know if there is some way to do it in VS 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer propsosed in the linked question is still pretty much valid, but you have to think it through a bit.

First of all the actual answer remains: it's simply not possible to get the assembly name onto the debug command line using the project settings.

Second there are a couple of things you can do however:

1. The debugger command line is stored in the projectname.vcxproj.user file as the `LocalDebuggerCommandArguments` property. Write a script/extension/... to set that property to `$(TargetPath)` and off you go.
2. Based on the solution propsed in the other question: use an external tool with something like `devenv /DebugExe powershell.exe - Command { Import-Module $(TargetPath) }`.
3. Like 2, but place a `DebugBreak()` statement somwhere in your dll and just launch PowerShell, it will coma and ask to attach the debugger when it sees DebugBreak/add.